# C++ cleaning the console window

Tags: c++, console

IS there a way to delete or rewrite a symbol on the console window? Something like System("cls") but for a single symbol.

Thanks

Comment: Printing a lot of `(char)8` (backspace) might do it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Or `'\b'`. :)

Comment: `\b` doesn't erase anything, "\b \b" does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are usually working with *standard output stream* with C++, not with console itself. And you are not able to navigate through it.

From the other hand, you can use specific platform dependent console libraries (like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) or [Windows console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to handle console.

However, if you are actually printing to the console you can use some symbols to control the last line:

- You can send `'\b'` (<kbd>Backspace</kbd>) to move one character left on the current line.
- You can send `'\r'` to move to the beginning of the current line.

Don't forget also, that `stdout` usually line-buffered and you may have to *flush* by hands.

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hi\r" << std::flush;
    Sleep(1000); //or whatever to delay
    std::cout << "hellq" << std::flush; // flushing by hands
    Sleep(1000);
    std::cout << "\bo";
}
```